# firebase data to recyclerview in fragment

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

This is my first time building an application and I have a problem with making a Recyclerview in a fragment with data from Firebase firestore & storage.
java.lang.NullPointerException: recycle_view must not be null

this is my data class

```
data class Wallitem (
    var title:String,
    var image:String,
    var ref:String,
    var price:String,
    var students:String
)
```

and this is my adapter.kt

```
class WallAdapter(private var items: ArrayList<Wallitem>, private val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<WallAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items[position]
        Glide.with(context).load(item.image).into(holder.titleImage)
        holder.titleTextView.text = item.title
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val i = Intent(context, CoursePage::class.java)
            val courseName: String = item.title
            val image: String = item.image
            val ref: String = item.ref
            val price: String = item.price
            val students: String = item.students
            i.putExtra("courseName", courseName)
            i.putExtra("courseImage", image)
            i.putExtra("ref", ref)
            i.putExtra("coursePrice", price)
            i.putExtra("courseStudents", students)
            context.startActivity(i)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return items.size
    }
    class ViewHolder(view: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view!!) {
        val titleImage:ImageView = view!!.findViewById(R.id.titleImageView)
        val titleTextView:TextView = view!!.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView)
    }
}
```

and this is my Fragment.kt (onCreateView part)

```
private lateinit var adapter: WallAdapter
override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val items:ArrayList<Wallitem> = ArrayList()
        recycle_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL,false)
        adapter = WallAdapter(items,view.context)

        val db : FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        val storage : FirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
        storage.maxDownloadRetryTimeMillis = 60000
        storage.maxOperationRetryTimeMillis = 10000

        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        LoadingTextView.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        db.collection("courses").get()
                .addOnSuccessListener {documents ->
                    for(document: QueryDocumentSnapshot in documents){
                        val wallItem = document.toObject(Wallitem::class.java)
                        //got title images
                        val storageRef: StorageReference = storage.reference.child("courses").child("images").child(document.id)
                        storageRef.list(1).addOnCompleteListener {result ->
                            val items:List<StorageReference> = result.result!!.items
                            //got first elements from the list to set title image
                            items.first().downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                                Log.d("storage " ,"$it")
                                wallItem.image = it.toString()
                                wallItem.ref = document.id
                                wallItem.title = document["courseName"].toString()
                                wallItem.price = document["price"].toString()
                                wallItem.students = document["students"].toString()
                                //if you need you may sort
                                recycle_view.adapter = adapter
                            }
                        }
                        items.add(wallItem)
                    }
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.d("fail","Error getting document $it")
                }.addOnCompleteListener {
                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    LoadingTextView.visibility = View.GONE
                }

        return view
    }
```

Comment: if your error is saying `recycle_view must not be null` then we should probably look at where you're creating an instance of your recycler view. in the code you've posted, where are you assigning an instance to it ?

Comment: thanks for your replay i solv the error by creating an instance of recycler view in onViewCreated